# Is there a way to give rights to deploy things on AKS with terraform without giving cluster admin rights?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

We are working with AKS clusters, and we are trying to split the level of rights on these clusters in order to have :

- Cluster admin, who will manage the cluster, update it, etc
- Cluser users, who will deploy nodes, pods, configure cronjobs, ect

To deploy things on AKS, we are using terraform.

For admins profile, no issue while doing plan and apply. The connection is done as admin, so no problem to terraform plan and apply.

The issue comes with the user profile. When a user, with right to list namespace at clusterrole level, and rights inside his own namespace, try to do a terraform plan, he get an 403 Unauthorized error.

But at the same time, the same user profile can connect to the cluster with cli without problem, and doing the things whiches are allow by his rights.

So the question is quite simple : is it possible to use terraform to deploy on AKS with a user profil, or is it necessary to connect to the cluster with an admin profile ?
The goal is to allow developpers to deploy things on their own namespaces with terraform.

For your information, on terraform, we are using the solution with the config_path = "~/.kube/config"

Comment: Terraform requires cluster-level permissions to assess the state and manage resources at the desired level. Terraform not only needs permissions for the resources it directly controls, but also for reading other resources in the cluster to plan and execute changes correctly so for the user we also need read access to the cluster @Lexo1707

Answer (score 0):

> Rights to deploy things on AKS with terraform without giving cluster admin rights.

To understand the requirement the main blockers which causes the issue is

- Terraform requires cluster-admin rights for most operations due to the way it interacts with the Kubernetes API server.
- While your cluster user has specific namespace-level permissions via Cluster Role, Terraforms default behavior might attempt actions beyond these limitations

To achieve this we can use Service Account approach for deploying to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) with Terraform, follow these steps

#### Create a Service Account in Kubernetes bind the Service Account to a Cluster Role and Retrieve the Service Account Token

**`service-account.yaml`**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: terraform-deployer
  namespace: default
```

**`role-binding.yaml`**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: terraform-deployer-binding
  namespace: default # Change this to your namespace if needed
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
  permissions to manage resources
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: terraform-deployer
  namespace: default
```

now run the commands below

```
kubectl apply -f service-account.yaml
```

&

```
kubectl apply -f role-binding.yaml
```

[image]

now run the namespace configuration with the user profiles without admin role

***terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://vksbaks1-mg7.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io"
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(var.cluster_ca_certificate)
  token                  = var.service_account_token
}

variable "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  description = "The cluster CA certificate"
  type        = string
}

variable "service_account_token" {
  description = "The Service Account token"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}


resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "testvk-namespace"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "testvk-deployment"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.example.metadata[0].name
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 3

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "example"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "example"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.14.2"
          name  = "example"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***deployment succeeded:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It confirm that it's not possible to deploy things on AKS with a non admin account. So we will manage terraform deployment with a Service principal through DevOps pipeline.

Comment: yes, @Lexo1707 You need those privileges.